# How to correctly parse Json Objects from text Stream delimited by new lines

Tags: javascript, streaming, fetch-api

I have written some code to read JSON objects from a stream returned from a fetch API. However, I am unable to successfully parse out the JSON objects successfully. I want return the JSON objects from the chunks in a array and feed the results to a transformer that will apply some custom transformation the the final JSON. However, I am unable to deal with the partial chunks that result from the chunks after splitting the chunks into new lines. My main problem is I don't know how the chunking format looks from the data returned in the stream. I have written some code which does not work entirely. I am looking for some help to get it parsing out all the JSON objects.  Here is my code that attempts to do that. First, I wrote an async iterator that works fine. Next, i use that to split the chunks into new lines

```js
             function streamAsyncIterator(stream) {
                const reader = stream.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).getReader();

                return {
                  next() {
                  return reader.read();
                },
              

               return() {
                 reader.releaseLock();
                 return {};
               },
              [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
              return this;
             }
           };
          }
```

Next, I use the iterator to to get new lines to convert to JSON objects; Here is that code, which partially works:

```js
                   const fetchProductsStream = async () => {
                     const body = {
                        searchRange: ['fragrance', 'perfumery', 'cologne'],
                        exclusionCategory: ['discounted']        
                     }
                     let time1 = performance.now();

                     const response = await fetch('/products/stream', {
                       method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify(body)
                      });
                     let chunkCount = 0;
                     let remaining = "";
                     let currentChunk = "";
                     let totalItems = 0;

                    for await (const chunk of streamAsyncIterator(response.body)) {
                      let items = [];
                      try{
                        currentChunk = chunk;
                        let lastIndex;
                        if(remaining.trim().length > 1){
                          currentChunk = remaining + chunk;
                       }
                      currentChunk.split(/\r?\n/).forEach((line, index) => {
                         try{
                           items.push(JSON.parse(line));
                           console.log(`Pushed line ${line} to items array`);
                           lastIndex = index;  
                         }catch(err){
                           console.error(`Error is ${err}`);
                         }
                       })
                           totalItems += items.length;
                           remaining = "";

                           let i = currentChunk.indexOf(lastIndex);
                           if(i != -1){
                            remaining = currentChunk.substring(lastIndex);
                           }
                           items = [];
           
                         }catch(error){
                          console.log(error);
                        }
                        chunkCount++;
                      }
      
                        let time2 = performance.now();
                        console.log(`Total number of items is ${totalItems}`);
                        console.log(`Total number of chunks :: ${chunkCount} in time 
                         ${(time2 - time1)/1000} seconds`)
                   }
```

Here is what a sample looks like

"{"productId":"1671","category":"fragrance","categoryId":1WW23,"productName":"Paco Rabane","productClass":"M","warehouseCode":"1242","alternateName":"ALT_ELL332"}\n{"productId":"1671","category":"fragrance","categoryId":1WW23,"productName":"Paco Rabane","productClass":"M","warehouseCode":"1242","alternateName":"ALT_ELL332"}\n{"productId":"1671","category":"fragrance","categoryId":1WW23,"productName":"Paco Rabane","productClass":"M","warehouseCode":"1242","alternateName":"ALT_ELL332","category":{"desc":"1654 Cologne Perfume","code":"221","feature":"1","salesCode":"S2237"}\n{"productId":"1671","category":"fragrance","categoryId":1WW23,"productName":"Paco Rabane","productClass":"M","warehouseCode":"1242","alternateName":"ALT_ELL332"}"

```
This is my attempt, which does not work perfectly, since there are some json objects that are not correctly parsed. Most of them are, so I'd appreciate some help in getting it to work perfectly. If there is a better way to do it, I will also be grateful for that solution.
```

Comment: It would help to list a sample JSON that is split into junks. Is it an array of objects? Some other structure?

Comment: It contains company proprietary information. This stream is a standard output from buffers translated into text streams. It is delimited by new lines. It is initially the data that would be in a Node buffer and specified by the Streams Standard API.

Comment: I get that, but without a made up example of a JSON object that is split into junks we are poking in the dark. Basically you need to construct a valid JSON object from partial data, and save the rest for the next chunk.

Comment: I have edited the sample JSON from the stream and included it. Thank you

Comment: Are the chunks aligned with the newlines? In other words, does a chunk always start with `"{\"productId\"`, or is the start of a chunk anywhere in an object? Also, the data is not JSON, but key/value pairs can be guessed except for the last one: `\"alternateName\"&\"ALT_ELL332"` . What is the `&`?

Comment: It always start with quotes.  The only thing consistent is that are newlines that delimit complete JSON chunks. Also the JSON text in not on the same line, the chunks continue over multiple lines. The chunks do not always start with ""{productId:\", it starts arbitrarily, that's why I am using the remainder attempting to join to the next chunk

Comment: I am still not clear. Your example looks like three strings, where each string is a JSON-ish object. Could you convert that into an example array of chunks?

Comment: For the most part the stream starts with "{\"productId\" etc.  It also terminates with new lines. However, here is a section of output that I print out that does not start that way.  RAW CHUNK RESPONSE IS productClass":"M","categoryCode":"220203","alternateName":"ALT_ELL333",......"}

Comment: They are all JSON objects. However they are a stream of bytes, that's why I convert them using the TextDecoderStream. The bytes are arbitrary but chunk data from a streaming library are always newline delimited. However, since they are stored in javascript buffers, they can start at arbitray positions. They whole stream is a stream of JSON objects from a database in text format i.e. convert ed from the byte buffer. The only certain thing is that chunked data is always separated by new lines.

Comment: Here is the standard: https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#example-read-all-chunks

Comment: The & is just part of product code and not part of the chunk delimiting characters. It marks legacy products.

Comment: I find this still confusing, and I worked with streams & assembling JSON from chunks before. 1. Your sample is not a or multiple JSON strings. 2.  RAW example is not a valid JSON string, e.g. is missing the starting bracket. To simplify, how about posting 3 chunks as an array of strings? Such as: `[ '{ "k1": "a1", "k2": "a2" }\\n', '{ "k1": "b1", "k2": "b2" }\\n', '{ "k1": "c1", ', '"k2": "c2" }\\n' ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250735/discussion-between-breendeen-and-peter-thoeny).